# how to match file name in the file using python

Tags: python, pattern-matching

How to find out if two file exists with same pattern inside a file.If all filenames have two-set of filenames ( csv.new and csv) then go ahead to next step otherwise exit with error message.

The prefix "abc_package" will have two files one with extension "csv.new" and second file with extension "csv". There could be many filenames inside the "list_of_files.txt".

Ex: List_of_files.txt

```
abc_package.1406728501.csv.new
abc_package.1406728501.csv
abc_package.1406724901.csv.new
abc_package.1406724901.csv
```

Comment: what do you expect from your input, what is considered the same pattern?

Comment: Are the pairs always adjacent? And by "many" do you mean hundreds of millions (too much to fit in memory), or just like 50000?

Comment: yes file will be in given format. I meant around 15-20 filenames in the file not just 4 as given in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("in.txt","r") as fo:
    f = fo.readlines()
    cs_new = set()
    cs = set()
    for ele in f:
        ele = ele.rstrip()
        if not ele.endswith(".new"):
            cs.add(ele)
        else:
            cs_new.add(ele.split(".new")[0])
    diff = cs ^ cs_new
    for fi in diff:
        print fi
```

As you need either filename you will need to check for the existence against both lists:

```
with open("in.txt","r") as f:
    f = [x.rstrip() for x in f]
    cs, cs_new, diff = [],[],[]
    for ind, ele in enumerate(f):
        if ele.endswith(".csv"):
            cs.append(ele)
        else:
            cs_new.append([ele.split(".new")[0],ind]) # keep track of original element in with the ind/index
    for ele in cs:
        if not any(ele in x for x in cs_new):
            diff.append(ele)
    for ele in cs_new:
        if not any(ele[0] in x for x in cs):
            diff.append(f[ele[1]]) # append original element with full extension
```

Comment: Thanks so much . It worked as expected but only thing how to print file names which does not have matching file in error message.

Comment: If you loop over se.symmetric_difference... you can print out all the non matches

Comment: Why create an empty set and update it instead of just doing `se = set(cs)`? For that matter, why not use a set comprehension in the first place, unless working in pre-2.7 Python is a requirement?

Comment: After I update code to below it worked but not in all cases like when add these 2 filename abc_package.1416728501.csv.new  and abc_package.1426728501.csv.                                                     me = set()
me.update(csn)
print se.symmetric_difference(me)

Comment: do you want to print the files that do not have a `.new` or just an error message?

Comment: I want to print if all files match, if csv are missing , .new are missing in all three cases with exit out.

Comment: so there can be .new and no .csv yes?

Comment: yes ..there could be possibility. The modified code has set for "csn" and then comparing using symmetric_difference.

Comment: I think you will need different code to check for both, you need to be printing the .new also if it does not have a corresponding .csv, do you want to print the full filename including the .new?

Comment: yes I need to print full file names if they don't have corresponding files as of now even though "abc_package.1416728501.csv.new" does not have corresponding .csv it does not tell me same is case for abc_package.1426728501.csv.

Comment: that is what I meant, I will add that

Answer (score 6):

For matching the file name name in python you can use [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) module..I will provide you a sample code from the documentation.

```
import fnmatch
import os

for file in os.listdir('.'):
if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
    print file
```

The syntax would be `fnmatch.fnmatchcase(filename, pattern)`

Please have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) for more examples

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file isn't so ridiculously huge that you can't fit it into memory, just create a set of all `.csv.new` files and a set of all `.csv` files and verify that they're identical. For example:

```
csvfiles = set()
newfiles = set()
with open('List_of_files.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.endswith('.csv.new'):
            newfiles.add(line[:-4])
        elif line.endswith('.csv'):
            csvfiles.add(line)
if csvfiles != newfiles:
    raise ValueError('Mismatched files!')
```

If you want to know which files were mismatched, `csvfiles - newfiles` gives you the `.csv` files without corresponding `.csv.new`, and `newfiles - csvfiles` gives you the opposite.

(There are ways to make this cleaner and more readable, from using `os.path.splitext` to using a general partition-an-iterable-by-filter function, but I think this should be the easiest for a novice to immediately understand.)

Comment: Thanks so much , it is working like a charm but as you said there are other options too, are there any disadvantages to use it?

Comment: Going by my example, `os.path.splitext` is better in that it makes it more obvious what the code means (it's splitting off an extension, rather than splitting of 4 characters), and it gives you fewer places to get things wrong (everyone has used `[:-3]` at least once and left a stray `.` behind…). The disadvantage is that if you're writing the code to teach someone else, and he doesn't know what `os.path.splitext` means, he'll have to go look it up before understanding the answer. (Which is actually good sometimes, but maybe not for a quick SO answer.)

Comment: @user3896656: As for writing a more general partitioning function: the advantage is that it's reusable, and it makes the code much more declarative (each line does exactly what it says); the disadvantage is that it takes longer to think up and write, and it's harder to explain to novices.